# How to get object inside array and add it to parent object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have data like this :

```
data = {
  data: [
    {
      Email: 'test@yopmail.com',
      name: 'dsadas',
      amount: '43.243.434',
      date: '22 Januari 2022',
    },
    {
      Email: 'test@yopmail.com',
      name: 'akdasd',
      amount: '3.234',
      date: '12 Februari 2022',
    },
    {
      Email: 'test@yopmail.com',
      name: 'dasdasd',
      amount: '234.324',
      date: '10 Februari 2022',
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to get the first array data inside `data` and add it to parent object.

this is what I expected :

```
data = {
  Email: 'test@yopmail.com',
  name: 'dsadas',
  amount: '43.243.434',
  date: '22 Januari 2022',
  data: [
    {
      Email: 'test@yopmail.com',
      name: 'dsadas',
      amount: '43.243.434',
      date: '22 Januari 2022',
    },
    {
      Email: 'test@yopmail.com',
      name: 'akdasd',
      amount: '3.234',
      date: '12 Februari 2022',
    },
    {
      Email: 'test@yopmail.com',
      name: 'dasdasd',
      amount: '234.324',
      date: '10 Februari 2022',
    }
  ]
}
```

I was trying using map and pushing to object but still no luck

How to solve that ?

Please let me know if you need more information if it's still not enough

Comment: For most control you could just rebuild the entire thing with reduce if your goal to add more advanced filtering on it in the future: 
https://jsfiddle.net/6cszrfp2/
#DOCS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply use a spread operator syntax here to individually add all elements of the first array entry to the initial object.

```
const initialData = {
    data: [
        {
            Email: 'test@yopmail.com',
            name: 'dsadas',
            amount: '43.243.434',
            date: '22 Januari 2022',
        },
        {
            Email: 'test@yopmail.com',
            name: 'akdasd',
            amount: '3.234',
            date: '12 Februari 2022',
         },
         {
            Email: 'test@yopmail.com',
            name: 'dasdasd',
            amount: '234.324',
            date: '10 Februari 2022',
         }
    ]
};

const finalData = { ...initialData.data[0], ...initialData };
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to apply the source's properties to target object,
Check [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) method.

```js
const yourData = {
  data: [
    {
      Email: 'test@yopmail.com',
      name: 'dsadas',
      amount: '43.243.434',
      date: '22 Januari 2022',
    },
    {
      Email: 'test@yopmail.com',
      name: 'akdasd',
      amount: '3.234',
      date: '12 Februari 2022',
    },
    {
      Email: 'test@yopmail.com',
      name: 'dasdasd',
      amount: '234.324',
      date: '10 Februari 2022',
    }
  ]
};

Object.assign(yourData, yourData.data[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an iteration too :

```js
var obj = {
  data: [
    {
      Email: 'test@yopmail.com',
      name: 'dsadas',
      amount: '43.243.434',
      date: '22 Januari 2022',
    },
    {
      Email: 'test@yopmail.com',
      name: 'akdasd',
      amount: '3.234',
      date: '12 Februari 2022',
    },
    {
      Email: 'test@yopmail.com',
      name: 'dasdasd',
      amount: '234.324',
      date: '10 Februari 2022',
    }
  ]
}


Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj.data[0]).forEach((e) => {
  obj[e] = obj.data[0][e]
})

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var ab = {
  data: [
    {
      Email: 'test@yopmail.com',
      name: 'dsadas',
      amount: '43.243.434',
      date: '22 Januari 2022',
    },
    {
      Email: 'test@yopmail.com',
      name: 'akdasd',
      amount: '3.234',
      date: '12 Februari 2022',
    },
    {
      Email: 'test@yopmail.com',
      name: 'dasdasd',
      amount: '234.324',
      date: '10 Februari 2022',
    }
  ]
}
var firstIttem = ab.data[0]
var abc = {
    Email: firstIttem.Email,
    name: firstIttem.name,
    amount: firstIttem.amount,
    date: firstIttem.date,
    data: [...ab.data]
}
console.log(abc)
```